# Where can I find the template files for project item templates I've added via Extension Manager in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

Specifically, I've installed the extensions:

- `EF 4.x DbContext Generator for C#`
- `EF 4.x DbContext Generator for C# Web Sites`

I am trying to find the location these were installed, because I would like to modify them for my own needs.

I have looked in the following locations:

- `[UserDir]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\My Exported Templates`
- `[VSDir]\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033`

But they are not in either location.

### More Background

What I have done is modify the T4 template that generates the POCO's to pull info about the Max Length of text fields, have it generate a constructor for all objects (the default only generates an explicit constructor if there are complex types/relations that need to be instantiated), and add a partial method call to the Constructor for further initialization in a partial class.

The code that I have added is going to be needed in basically every project I do, so I would like to have my own code generation template for my POCO's, instead of having to modify the default one each time.

So, I'm looking for where those templates are so I can modify them, to create new ones with my changes inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff363239.aspx):
*During installation, Extension Manager uncompresses the .vsix file and puts its contents in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions\Company\Product\Version. Company, Product, and Version are specified in the extension.vsixmanifest file, and correspond to the namespace, project name, and version number that are set in the project properties.*

But strange, I also cannot find. I tried to install DbContextCSharp.vsix and find the content file (CSharpDbContext.Context.tt) of the installer. [*You can unzip the installer by changing vsix to zip extension*]

One thing I can suggest is, unzip the installer > update with your logic > change the extension back > re-install to visual studio.

Comment: Very good info. I'm going to dig some more and see what I find. I hadn't thought of taking the vsix, unzipping it, and working from that! +1

Answer (score -2):

I marked [Min Min's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9613895/237838) as Accepted because he found what I needed in MSDN: the location those files are installed:

> %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions\Company\Product\Version

For the extensions I sought, that amounted to:

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions\Microsoft\EF 4.x DbContext Generator for C#\1.0.2.0

Min Min stated he could not find the `DbContextCSharp.vsix` file nor the `CSharpDbContext.Context.tt` file. I assume he did this by doing a search, and indeed, those files are nowhere to be found on my system, either.

However, going to the indicated directory does locate the installed files. The `vsix` won't be there, however, and the content files are locked up in a ZIP file - hence those files could not be found via search. But everything needed is there and can be altered as needed.